# Applying a function to each instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class

I'm working on building a form validation program for practice in which I am using classes to store each field's related information. One of the operations I want to do is when the user submits the form any invalid fields will be highlighted and the user will be asked to correct them. The simplest thing to do would be to just apply a function to do this to each field, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Since all of these form "field sets" store their data in the same type of class, *formField*, it should be possible to loop through all of the *formField* classes applying a function to them right? I imagine that you could somehow stick the thing into an array, but is there any simpler way to do it than that?

The goal is to look at each instance of the *formField* class and change the background color of the *.field* value if its paired *.valid* value is false.

```
class formField{
  constructor(type){
    this.field = $(type.get(0));
    this.info = $(type.get(1));
    this.valid = false;
  }
}

function charLimit(form, min, max){
  if (form.field.val().length >= min && form.field.val().length <=max && form.field.val().length > 0){
  form.info.text(max + " character limit, " + (max - form.field.val().length) + " characters remaining");
    form.valid = true;
  }
  else if (form.field.val().length <= 0){
    form.info.text("");
    form.valid = false;
  }
  else if (form.field.val().length > max){
    form.info.text(max + " character limit, " + (form.field.val().length - max) + " characters over");
    form.valid = false;
  }
  else if (form.field.val().length < min){
    form.info.text(min + " character minimum, " + (min - form.field.val().length) + " characters under");
    form.valid = false;
  }
  else {
    form.info.text("");
    form.valid = false;
  }
}

function unmark(form){
  if (form.valid === true){
    form.field.css({'background-color' : 'initial'})
    form.info.css({'color': 'initial'});
  }
}

let username = new formField($('.un'));
username.field.on("keyup", function(){
  charLimit(username, 4, 32);
  unmark(username);
});

let password = new formField($('.pw'));
password.field.on("keyup", function(){
  charLimit(password, 6, 16);
  unmark(password);
});

let passwordConfirm = new formField($('.pwc'));
passwordConfirm.field.on("keyup", function(){
  if (passwordConfirm.field.val() == password.field.val()){
    passwordConfirm.info.text("passwords match");
    passwordConfirm.valid = true;
  }
  else {
    passwordConfirm.info.text("The passwords do not match");
    passwordConfirm.valid = false;
  }
  unmark(passwordConfirm);
});

let comment = new formField($('.cmnt'));
comment.field.on("keyup", function(){
  charLimit(comment, 4, 140);
  unmark(comment);
});


function validate(form){
  if (form.valid !== true){
    form.field.css({'background-color' : 'red'})
    form.info.css({'color': 'red'});
  }
}

$('#button').on("click", function(){
  validate(username);
  validate(password);
  validate(passwordConfirm);
  validate(comment);
});
```

No matter how much I look at this I can't help but feel that I could have done this much more efficiently.

Comment: This may seem like a lot to take in, but have a read of this - it'll cover everything you have there, without any script whatsoever... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: @Archer he wants to do it in JS i believe , Jacob , mate have a look at some open source plugins and how they work , play around with the code and try and understand why the author has written the code the way he has written , Looking at a pro's code and understanding it and implementing it and improving on it is probably the best way of learning , your learning to code EFFICIENTLY while at the same time learning to CODE.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik That's why I posted a comment - not an answer ;)

Comment: LOL cool bro :)

Comment: @Jacob , look into parsley.js http://parsleyjs.org/

Comment: Do you mean CSS class (eg: `required`) or the FormField JS class which currently doesn't have much above?

Answer (score 0):

A more ideal way would be to have a single class for Validation, including the validation methods.

```
class Validation {
  constructor (rules) {
    this.userRules = rules;
  }

  methods = {
    'required': function () {
      //
    },
    'maxlength': function () {
      //
    },
  }

  check () {
    for (let rule of rules)
      rule.rules.each (method) {
        this.methods[method].call()...
      }
    }
  }
}


// Usage
var validation = new Validation ({
  '#name': {
    rules: ['maxlength', 'required']
  },
  '#email': {
    rules: ['email', 'required']
  },
  // ...
});

function submit () {
  validation.check(callback)
}
```

Comment: Note, you can also pass form object directly, or any input, and based on that just handle the check accordingly